Strategy for Implementing Dynamic Routes with SSR in Nuxt 3 (Umbraco)
I am in the process of upgrading a project from Vue 2 to Vue 3, using Nuxt 3 to implement server-side rendering (SSR). The application interacts with an Umbraco v12 backend from which it dynamically fetches routing information for various sections such as blogs, articles, and categories. Each type of content has specific URLs that need to be dynamically handled by Nuxt.
I tried to fetch the routes api in the server/middleware and set them in the pinia store to make plugin that will save the extendRoutes and use it as dynamic routes for each of the component.

Good start: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/pages#dynamic-routes
